# hibernate update query composite key example

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have hibernate reverse engineering  generated classes with composite keys. I want to update my table column (i.e) non composite key using composite keys. I tried, but no exceptions came,not working my query.

```
 Query query= session.createQuery(update textvalues d  set d.mytext=:newtext"+"where d.id.firstId=:firstId and d.id.secondid=:secondId ");
```

Here, mytext is a column of textvalues table. firstId , secondId are composite keys. It works if I update the id value alone, but not working for mytext column but executes well. I am not good at debugging, but when i did it, i got **org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException**

```
control not come after or execute after this line **session.createQuery()**
```

Comment: Well that piece of HQL you post there is lacking some spaces between the keywords, so I can't believe that is really what you are using. Post the actual code, using the code button to nicely format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a stab in the dark here...

```
  update textvalues d  
     set d.mytext = :newtext
   where d.firstid = :firstId 
     and d.secondid = :secondId
```

Comment: setString() or which method most preferable?not working again , it compiles well, control not moved after session.createQuery()??

Comment: duck fish banana headache